# Gallery Images disapeares recently in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery

recently I have faced a problem with tow sites running wordpress, that is Image gallery item list are displayed without the image itself , i.e **the pruduced html code does not include the image**, they are empty. 
does any body have an idea about this issue?
**link of situation  :** http://istanbulpic.com/ist/index.php/downloads/category/people/
given that the content is already exists.